# C++ Помощь с заданием, связанной с функций

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <clocale>
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, fact, sumfact, e;
    e = 0;
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    printf("Введите целочисленное число - n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    fact = 1;
    float x, s;
    printf("Введите число - x ");
    scanf_s("%f", &x);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sumfact = i + n;
        for (int r = 1; r <= sumfact; r++)
        {
            fact = fact * r;
        }
        e = e + x / fact;
        fact = 1;
        sumfact = 0;
    }
    printf("%d", e);
}
```

Помогите, в чем ошибка, выводит ноль , может ошибка в типе данных? Или в чем? Спасибо
[image: Задание]

Comment: переменная `fact` должна быть `float` а не `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема в целочисленности:

у вас сумма целочислена, хотя каждый ее компонент может быть меньше 1, что в свою очередь приводит к нулевому результату

```
int n, fact, sumfact, e;
e = e + x / fact;
```

кроме того на результат вы опять выводите как целочисленный - хотя он представляет собой число с плавающей запятой

```
printf("%d", e);
```

переменная `s` у вас вообще не используется - возможно вы ее хотели в качестве суммы использовать, но забыли

вот так же гораздо чище?

```
setlocale(0, "rus");

int n;
std::cout << "Введите целочисленное число - n: ";
std::cin >> n;

float x;
std::cout << "Введите число - x: ";
std::cin >> x;

float sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    float fact = 1;
    for (int r = 1; r <= i + n; r++)
    {
        fact *= r;
    }

    sum += x / fact;
}

std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу Zhihar - ну не вычисляются факториалы явно, не нужны они здесь. Как и постоянное умножение на x - но это грех поменьше... Смотрите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А значит, хотя бы так:

```
double sum = 0, term = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) term *= i;
term = 1/term;
for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
{
    term /= N+i;
    sum += term;
}
sum *= x;
```

Сравните сами количество выполняемых арифметических операций...